# read csv file and write into database

Tags: php

:)

I have a csv file like this:

```
Date;             00003 A;  00003 B;  00004 A;  00004 B
21.04.2020 15:14; 16,2;     38;       22,4;     33,8
21.04.2020 15:19; 17,8;     36,3;     22,4;     34,1
```

this php code read the csv file:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen('myFile.csv', 'r');
while($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';')) {

   echo "<tr>";
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
      echo "<td>".$data[$i]."</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

the result:

[image]

Explanation:
00003 A;  00003 B;  00004 A;  00004 B
00003 and 0004 are devices
A = min value
B = max value

my csv file will gernate every hour.
my script shoul read the file and write this values into my mysql database.

have you any idea which way will be the best practices to write it into the database.
for example: which tables should I use?
which table structure?

Thanks !

Comment: The answers to "*Which tables should I use?*" and "*Which table structure?*" will be extremely dependent on exactly what you're attempting to eventually do with the data.

Comment: later I would be able to send a query like: show me all min values where device id = x from date x - y

Comment: I would imagine a simple table containing five fields - unique id, datetime, device id, min and max would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fixed columns, go with same structure, but if you how know how many columns you will have in future, make them rows.

table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE devices ( 
       date DateTime(), 
       device VARCHAR(20),
       value FLOAT(8,2)
);
```

then you save them as

```
insert into `devices` Values (date, device, value) 
(21.04.2020 15:14,'00003 A',16,2),
(21.04.2020 15:19,'00003 B',38)
```

finally

```
select device, min(value) as minvalue
from devices
group by device where device = '00003 A' and date > '21.04.2020 15:14'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just google "php mysql insert" and you'll find your answer.

Try the following code, adpapt parameters, tablename and columns to whatever you want and it should be good:

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

(Source: from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: … and use prepared statements while you're at it.

Comment: I need no code. that was not my question

Comment: well, then your question is not clear at all, it's about "php" not about "databses"  and  your subject is "read csv file and write into database", so my answer should be the perfect answer to what you ask!

Answer (score 0):

you'r answer to yous sub-question: "have you any idea which way will be the best practices to write it into the database. for example: which tables should I use? which table structure?"

table name:

```
myFile
```

columns:

```
date
A3
B3
A4
B4
```

If that is not good, please reformulate your question. Also tag it with databse tags, not PHP, you'r post has in fact nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Don't add multiple answers, just edit it, its against stackoverflow rules